# Which versions/libraries do I need to get PHP running on Win 7 with Apache 2 (64bit)?

Tags: php, apache, vcredist

I have been having trouble getting PHP to install on my 64-bit Win 7 machine with Apache. I'm new to installing software that doesn't come shrink-wrapped and I have run out of useful docs/links to read.

Here is what I have done:

1. Installed Apache 2.4.18 win64 (which is built with VC14) from Apache Lounge. This works - my browser says "It works!" when I visit my docroot.
2. Downloaded the VC14 x64 Thread Safe (2016-Jan-06 23:30:09) PHP zip from windows.php.net and extracted it to c:/php.
3. Added *LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"* to httpd.conf.
4. Downloaded VC_redist64.exe (version 14.0.23506) from Microsoft and installed it.
5. Tried httpd and I get:

   c:\Apache24\bin>httpd
   httpd: Syntax error on line 178 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php5_module' in file C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll: No error

I know I need to add/adjust more in httpd.conf and perhaps php.ini too, but all the help I have found on the web suggests that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: google for and download WAMP, which is the "shrink-wrapped" version of apache, mysql, php for windows. All you need is the c++ redistributable and it will give you a link to it on the downoad page if you don;t already have iit.

Comment: Thanks for WAMP which I didn't know about and seems to work but I need a PHP that works with my existing installation of Apache (I could have made that clearer I guess). I'll look into migrating my existing installation to WAMP but I would still prefer an independent installation of PHP.

Comment: Do you install the Apache 2.4 from [apache Lounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/)? By the way i suggest to everybody to install PHP hard way at least one time.

Comment: You have `LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"` Is it as simple as the missing directory seperator i.e. `LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php7/apache2_4.dll"`

Comment: @pamblam No, I don't think I am misunderstanding anything. I already have an extensive web site using python scripts to access a database. If I migrate to a WAMP-based solution then all of that work has to be moved and re-tested. It would have been much easier (it seems to me) if PHP could have been simply added to my existing installation.

Comment: @RiggsFolly. Good one! But sadly, no. The module really is called php7apache2_4.dll

Comment: Oh yea of course it is, silly me. OK how about this, have you added a `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` line to your `httpd.conf` file

Comment: Also you might like to add `index.php` to your `DirectoryIndex` in `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 6):

> LoadModule **php5_module** "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

you should change it to:

> LoadModule **php7_module** "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

Comment: it worked for me, i hope the person who asked the question marks this as right, cuz i had followed the same steps that he did

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the LoadModule with a directive to load php**5**apache2_4.dll from the Wamp distribution and there seem to be no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You're using PHP7, VC14. So instead of `php5_module`, use

`LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"`

Result:

```
c:\Apache24\bin>httpd -t
Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked all over the internet to get this fixed ... it was just a case-sensitive thing. I changed mine to:

```
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

and it fixed the issue.